# Ruby symbol and attribute

Tags: ruby

When I'm creating attributes, I can use symbols like this:

```
class SomeClass
  attr_reader :variable1, :variable2
end
```

When I'm using the keyword `attr_reader` (or `attr_writer`) and use the same name as some instance variable, does Ruby automatically associate the attribute (or say, property) with the instance variable with the same name?

Comment: What isn't clear about ["Creates instance variables and corresponding methods that return the value of each instance variable."](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader)? That's straight out of the `attr_reader` documentation.

Comment: That's cool, I didn't even know that website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand what `attr_reader` does. When you do:

```
attr_reader :variable1, :variable2
```

It gets translated into:

```
def variable1
  @variable1
end
def variable2
  @variable2
end
```

As you can see `variable1` is but the instance variable `@variable1` whose value you are setting within your `initialize` method.

So yes, Ruby does associate the attribute with the instance variable with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no association going on.

And `attr_reader`, `attr_writer`, `attr_accessor` aren't keywords, they are methods just like any other method. In fact, you can easily write them yourself:

```
class Module
  def attr_reader(*attrs)
    attrs.each do |attr|
      define_method(attr) { instance_variable_get(:"@#{attr}") }
    end
  end

  def attr_writer(*attrs)
    attrs.each do |attr|
      define_method(:"#{attr}=") do |val| instance_variable_set(:"@#{attr}", val) end
    end
  end

  def attr_accessor(*attrs)
    attr_reader *attrs
    attr_writer *attrs
  end
end
```

All that those methods do, is generate some other methods whose name is based on the symbol you pass into them. That's it.